# Linking scopes together in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm having the following quiz put together that pulls from a json and provides options for questions, etc.

```
            <div ng-repeat="question in module.questions | filter:{'number':module.path.subsection}" class="questionContainer {{question.class}}">
                <p ng-bind-html="question.title"></p>
                <label ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                    <input type="radio"
                           name="{{ question.title }}"
                           value="answer"
                           ng-model="qCtrl.selectedAnswers[question.title]">
                    <div class="question-box">{{ answer.answerLabel }}</div>
                    <!--<div class="{{ quizModel }}" ng-click="seeModel(module, section, subsection, question, quizModel)"></div>-->
                    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button ng-click="validate()">Submit</button><br />

            <p ng-if='qCtrl.totalQuestions'>{{ correctAnswers }}/{{ totalQuestions }} were correct.</p>
            </div>
```

And I have this controller for it:

```
.controller('QuizCtrl',
        function() {
            var ctrl = this;

            this.selectedAnswers = {};

            this.questions = [{
                'title': 'Question 1 ?',
                'answers': [{
                    'title': 'Answer 1',
                    'correct': false,
                }, {
                    'title': 'Answer 2',
                    'correct': true,
                }]
            }, {
                'title': 'Question 2 ?',
                'answers': [{
                    'title': 'Answer 1',
                    'correct': false,
                }, {
                    'title': 'Answer 2',
                    'correct': true,
                }]
            }]

            this.validate = function() {
                ctrl.correctAnswers = 0;
                ctrl.totalQuestions = ctrl.questions.length;

                for (var answer in ctrl.selectedAnswers) {
                    answerObj = ctrl.selectedAnswers[answer]
                    if (answerObj.correct) {
                        ctrl.correctAnswers += 1;
                    }
                }



            }
        });
```

Questions being, having discussed this with someone who is lot more skilled in Angular than I am, the problem seems to be in by function not pulling from the same scope or smth like that. PLUS, I really can't have a hard-coded array to pull questions from. I already have a Json for that. How do I make the validate function actually talk to the selected values in the questions?!

The Json structure is as follows:

```
sections: [
 subSections:[
  "questions":[
     "title":"a",
     "number":"b",
     "name":"c",
     "answers":[
       {
        "answerKey": "true",
        "answerLabel": "true"
       },
       {
         "answerKey": "false",
         "answerLabel": "false"
       }
     ]
   ] 
 ]
]
```

Comment: What exactly is "the problem"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I do think that you should be injecting the $scope in your controller and using it: 
app.controller('QuizCtrl', function($scope) ...

Comment: The problem is that the validate() function does not work. On console.log'ing any of the elements in that particular controller, nothing is returned. Literally. However I'm trying to grab those selected values - it's not working. :(

Comment: After adding $scope nothing has changed.

What I'm really trying to do probably is to grab those selected values, pass them into an array and then submit that array for evaluation to validate(). I'm just not sure how I'd grad that array dynamically from my existing json and from the values selected through the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo below that should helps you.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.answears = [];
  vm.questions = [{
    'id': '1',
    'title': 'Question 1 ?',
    'answers': [{
      'title': 'Answer 1',
      'correct': false,
    }, {
      'title': 'Answer 2',
      'correct': true,
    }]
  }, {
    'id': '2',
    'title': 'Question 2 ?',
    'answers': [{
      'title': 'Answer 1',
      'correct': false,
    }, {
      'title': 'Answer 2',
      'correct': true,
    }]
  }];

  vm.validate = function() {
    vm.correctAnswers = 0;
    vm.totalQuestions = vm.questions.length;
    angular.forEach(vm.answears, function(correct) {

      if (correct) {
        vm.correctAnswers++;
      }

    })

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="question in vm.questions" ng-init="index= $index">
      <p>{{question.title}}</p>
      <div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
        <label>{{ answer.title }}
          <input type="radio" name="{{question.title}}" ng-value="answer.correct" ng-model="vm.answears[index]" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="vm.validate()">Submit</button>
    <br /> <pre>{{vm.qCtrl}}</pre>

    <p ng-show="vm.totalQuestions">{{ vm.correctAnswers }}/{{ vm.totalQuestions }} were correct.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This would work with my current code (which I cannot post in its entirety due to its hugeness and company restrictions) for the exception of how ng-model works. When I set it to ng-model="answer.answerKey" is per the json structure, it automatically makes it so that once you click on the  radio button, all the rest of the questions are selected without your actually clicking on any of them.